# Call function in prototype from other prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two prototypes in my jquery script :

```
script1.prototype.initScript = function() {
  //first one
   this.saveGrid = function () {
   alert("here");
 }
};
script1.prototype.otherFunction = function () {
 //second
 //script1.initScript.saveGrid ?
};
```

I'd like to call `saveGrid` in `otherFunction`. How can I do that?

Edit :
And there ?

```
script1.prototype.initScript = function() {
  //first one
   this.saveGrid = function () {
   alert("here");
 }
};
script1.prototype.otherFunction = function () {
 //second
    $('button').on("click", function(){
     //call savegrid here
   });
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the function over `this`, like you already did in you example while creating the function `saveGrid`.

You should instead ask yourself, if this is a good idea, to create a function in another function and re-use them elsewere. What will happen, if you call `otherFunction` before `initScript`?

```js
function script1() {}

script1.prototype.initScript = function() {
    this.saveGrid = function() {
        alert("here");
    }
};

script1.prototype.otherFunction = function() {
    this.saveGrid();
};

var s = new script1();
s.initScript();
s.otherFunction();
```

For you second example you have to store `this` before creating your event listener.

```js
function script1() {}

script1.prototype.initScript = function() {
    this.saveGrid = function() {
        alert("here");
    }
};

script1.prototype.otherFunction = function() {
    var that = this;

    $('button').on("click", function(){
        that.saveGrid();
    });
};

var s = new script1();
s.initScript();
s.otherFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanation. And if `saveGrid` is in another function? I've edited my first message for an other situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prototype It depends on the type .
the correct way is defined as a prototype , so you can call them in different situations

```
script1.prototype.saveGrid=function () {
   alert("here");
 }
script1.prototype.initScript = function() {
  //first one
   this.saveGrid()
};
script1.prototype.otherFunction = function () {
 //second
 //this.saveGrid()
};`
```

or you can define an object which then associates the prototypes

```
  var script1=(function () {
function initScript(){
   this.saveGrid();
}
function otherFunction(){
   this.saveGrid();
}
script1.prototype.saveGrid=function () {
   alert("here");
 }
});
```